# Submit form does not work once table is transposed

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I need to transpose/rotate a table, in order to view it better, however as soon as I transpose the table the submit button will now work any more
I have a **table setup** as follows

```
<table id="tableID" width="200" border="1">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Date</td>
      <td>Boxed;</td>
      <td>Location</td>
      <td>Quantity</td>
      <td>Change;</td>
    </tr>
       <?php do { ?>
    <tr><form action="<?php echo $editFormAction; ?>" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="form1" id="form1">
      <td><?php echo $row_get['Date']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row_get['Boxed']; ?></td>
      <td><input name="Location" type="text" id="Location" value="<?php echo $row_get['Location']; ?>" size="7" /></td>
      <td><input name="Quantity" type="text" id="Quantity" value="<?php echo $row_get['Quantity']; ?>" size="7" /></td>
      <td><input name="Update" type="submit" value="submit" id="Update" />
        <input name="id" type="hidden" id="id" value="<?php echo $row_get['id']; ?>" />
        </p>
        <input type="hidden" name="MM_update" value="form1" />
</form></td>
    </tr> <?php } while ($row_get ->fetch()); ?>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

in the **transpose table script:**

```
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
 $( document ).ready(function() {
$("#tableID").each(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        var newTransposedRow = [];
        $this.find("tr").each(function(){
            var i = 0;
            $(this).find("td").each(function(){
                i++;
                if(newTransposedRow[i] === undefined) { newTransposedRow[i] = $("<tr></tr>"); }
                newTransposedRow[i].append($(this));
            });
        });
        $this.find("tr").remove();
        $.each(newTransposedRow, function(){
            $this.append(this);
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

**Update DB:**

```
$editFormAction = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
  $editFormAction .= "?" . htmlentities($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
}

if ((isset($_POST["MM_update"])) && ($_POST["MM_update"] == "form1")) {
  $updateSQL = "UPDATE Stock SET Location=?, Quantity=? WHERE id=?";

  $Result1= $conn->prepare($updateSQL) or die(errorInfo());
  $done = $Result1->execute([$_POST['Location'], $_POST['Quantity'], $_POST['Trade_price'],  $_POST['id']]);
if ($done){
header('Location: mypage.php
    exit();
    }
}
```

This all works fine until I use/insert the transposition script any idea what is stopping the update? 
Any help welcome

Comment: Fyi, I'd like you to read about `http_build_query()`.  Also `do-while()` loops aren't really great for fetching query results in case there aren'tany rows.

Comment: @mickmackusa Thanks for that, I just want to know I can correct and submit the form when it has transformed the table as Im not sure what Im doing wrong besides rotating the table?

Comment: I am expecting input attributes with `[]` after the letters.  If this is the problem, this is a duplicate.  We would like to see some sample data.  What does it look like before transposing? What does it look like after?  What exact structure do you need?  I'm not convinced that transposing in js is necessary.

Comment: @mickmackusa not sure what you mean with letters?

Comment: For example `name="Location[]"`.  Why aren't you just serializing the form data and sending it to php for processing?  You may find a way to make this work, but I don't think I'd use many of the techniques that you are using.

Comment: The problem is not with the input fields, it is as soon as I rotate the table with the script the update/submit will not work

Comment: Again, we'd like to see the data structures.  Please edit your question.  I am going away.  Good luck.

Comment: Your php loop is generating DOM elements with duplicated ids -- this is invalid markup.  You have form tags as direct children of tr tags -- this is invalid markup.  I have no idea why you need to use client-side scripting to transpose the form fields.  Just fetch all of your result set rows and structure the html table as you need using php. You don't need hidden fields, just add the `$row_get['id']` value as the submit button's `value` attribute.  If you need to associate row values with the `id`, then explicitly declare the keys `name="Quantity[$row_get['id']]"`.